# excel vba code copying values from an opened excel file into a string array in a efficient manner

Tags: vba, excel

I opened an excel file using

```
 exlFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a excel File", MultiSelect:=False)
 If exlFileName = False Then Exit Sub

Application.Workbooks.Open (exlFileName)
Worksheets("Fruits").Activate
Fruits=ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Basically I think now the fruits is just having the range value not the content.This is what I actually want
Suppose there is list of fruits in the opened excel sheet one in each line eg 1.Apple
2.Orange
3.Grapes
So I want the Fruits variable to have like Array("Apple","Orange","Grapes").I actually just have one long list of items in only 1 column in my excel sheet.Also please suggest an efficient method.

Comment: I would do for loop but likely not most efficient.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859531/excel-vba-populate-array-with-range-from-specific-sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only create a single-dimension array like this if you have 1 column of data. If this is case you could make a UDF with the following logic:

```
Function Val2Array(rng As Range) As Variant
    Val2Array = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng)
End Function

'// Example use:  

 exlFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a excel File", MultiSelect:=False)
 If exlFileName = False Then Exit Sub

Application.Workbooks.Open (exlFileName)
Worksheets("Fruits").Activate
Fruits = Val2Array(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1)) '// <~~~
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

You can create a single dimension array from a column in VBA by using the `WorksheetFunction.Transpose()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other suggestion but with error handling and ensuring only the actual usedrange of the column of interest (I used column A) is returned

```
Sub TEst()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim X

exlFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a excel File", MultiSelect:=False)
If exlFileName = False Then Exit Sub

Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(exlFileName)
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Sheets("Fruits")
On Error GoTo 0

If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
X = Application.Transpose(Range(ws.[a1], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))
Wb.Close False

End Sub
```